# HttpMessageNotReadableException: I/O error while reading input message; nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException

Tags: java, macos, api, rest

I have created an API to save an object in DB. whenever the hit comes to this API it gives correct response/output for some users but for some users (MACOS users) it gives an error mentioned below. I have tried a lot to resolve but still stuck init :

the request contains a data field which has a csv parsed data stringified. When someone adds a csv with more than 20 rows or csv size is more tan 500 kb the request doesn't goes through otherwise it does.
Also when running on local the api works fine.

```
DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP message: 
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: I/O error while reading input message; 
nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException.
```

**My code is:**

```
     @PostMapping("/abc")
        public ResponseEntity createObject(@RequestBody String jsonStr) throws Exception{
            ResponseEntity response = null;
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            ClassA abc = objectMapper.readValue(jsonStr, ClassA.class);
....
......
.......
            }
```

**Json that I am sending in a request is:**

```
{
  "userId": "",
  "sessionId": "",
  "inputValue": {
    "reqId": null,
    "viewId": null,
    "viewName": "test",
    "viewPurpose": "test",
    "viewDesc": "test",
    "pastRun": null,
    "variable": "",
    "criteria": "",
    "selectVariables": [
      "column d"
    ],
    "setId": null,
    "queryId": null,
    "viewConfig": "{\"rendererOptions\":{\"localeStrings\":{\"renderError\":\"An error occurred rendering the PivotTable results.\",\"computeError\":\"An error occurred computing the PivotTable results.\",\"uiRenderError\":\"An error occurred rendering the PivotTable UI.\",\"selectAll\":\"Select All\",\"selectNone\":\"Select None\",\"tooMany\":\"(too many to list)\",\"filterResults\":\"Filter values\",\"apply\":\"Apply\",\"cancel\":\"Cancel\",\"totals\":\"Totals\",\"vs\":\"vs\",\"by\":\"by\"},\"plotly\":{\"font\":{\"size\":10},\"width\":420,\"height\":300,\"showlegend\":true,\"isEditable\":false,\"gtitle\":\"\",\"xtitle\":\"\",\"ytitle\":\"\",\"lastUpdated\":\"\"},\"venn\":{\"isStaticVenn\":false,\"vennFilteredVariable\":[]}},\"localeStrings\":{\"renderError\":\"An error occurred rendering the PivotTable results.\",\"computeError\":\"An error occurred computing the PivotTable results.\",\"uiRenderError\":\"An error occurred rendering the PivotTable UI.\",\"selectAll\":\"Select All\",\"selectNone\":\"Select None\",\"tooMany\":\"(too many to list)\",\"filterResults\":\"Filter values\",\"apply\":\"Apply\",\"cancel\":\"Cancel\",\"totals\":\"Totals\",\"vs\":\"vs\",\"by\":\"by\"},\"derivedAttributes\":{},\"hiddenAttributes\":[],\"hiddenFromAggregators\":[],\"hiddenFromDragDrop\":[],\"menuLimit\":500,\"cols\":[\"column a \"],\"rows\":[],\"vals\":[],\"rowOrder\":\"key_a_to_z\",\"colOrder\":\"key_a_to_z\",\"labelOrder\":\"key_a_to_z\",\"exclusions\":{},\"inclusions\":{},\"unusedAttrsVertical\":85,\"autoSortUnusedAttrs\":false,\"showUI\":false,\"slicers\":[],\"slicerValues\":[],\"singleSelectVariables\":[],\"inputThresholds\":[],\"percentCheckbox\":false,\"percentAttribute\":\"\",\"sorters\":{},\"rendererName\":\"Bar Chart\",\"inclusionsInfo\":{},\"aggregatorName\":\"Count\",\"gtitle\":\"\",\"ytitle\":\"\",\"xtitle\":\"\"}",
    "data": "\"column a \",column b,column c,column d,column e\r\nwwdw,wqwq,assa,dsdsad,ewwe\r\nqwqweq,wqwq,sa,sa,ewwe\r\nwq,wqwq,sa,dsa,ewwe\r\nwq,wqe,sa,ds,ewr\r\nwqwq,rew,sas,d,ewr\r\nwq,ret,aas,asa,wer\r\nwq,re,sa,das,ewr\r\nwq,asas,d,sa,ewr\r\nwq,gg,assa,dsa,erw\r\nwq,gr,d,sda,ew\r\nwq,rt,s,sda,wer\r\nwq,tr,sdsd,dsa,erw\r\nwq,trgtr,sdsd,dsa,ewrewr\r\nwq,tr,sdsd,dsaa,wer\r\nwq,dasa,sdsd,asdsda,ewr\r\nwq,saas,sdsd,dsa,ewr\r\nqwqweq,saas,sdsd,dsa,ewr\r\nwqqw,tr,sdsd,sdaa,ewr\r\new,rg,ds,dsa,ewr\r\nweqw,ref,sdsd,das,ew\r\nw,efew,sdsd,dsa,wer\r\nqq,few,sdsd,ads,wer\r\nwq,wef,ds,dsa,ewr\r\nweqw,wef,sdsd,dsa,wer\r\newqweq,ewr,sdsd,dsa,wer\r\new,etr,ds,dsa,werewr\r\ne,ty,sdsd,dsadsa,ew\r\nwq,yt,sdsd,dsa,ewr\r\nwqe,yt,sdsd,dsa,weerw\r\nweqewq,yt,sdsd,das,ew\r\nwqe,yt,sdsd,dsa,ew\r\nwq,trtrg,sdsd,dsa,ew\r\newqweq,trgtr,sdsd,sda,wer",
    "reportType": 0,
    "singleValue": false,
    "createdBy": "abc",
    "createdDate": 1591782601097,
    "modifiedBy": "xyz",
    "modifiedDate": 1591782601097
  },
  "inputType": ""
}
```

Comment: It seems, there is some issue in reading the jsonString. Please post the actual code to better debug your issue. Provide your jsonString and the actual you are usiong to parse it.

Comment: Dear 007,
Thanks 2 reply. This API is giving response for some users & for some user it will throw an Exception (WARN  o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver:390 - Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: I/O error while reading input message; nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException).

Comment: I think few of the users are sending you wrong jsonString in the request.

Comment: Hey 007, I have posted the jsonString for the reference. All the users are sending the same jsonString but mostly Mac users are facing this issue and those who are working on windows getting the required response. Thanks Buddy for your helping hands. :)

Comment: Did you get a solution for this issue ?